# Multiple insert in mysql procedure throws error

Tags: mysql

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS 'proc_ico_150643';  
DELIMTER $$  
USE 'doc1vault'$$  
CREATE PROCEDURE 'proc_ico_150643'(

)  BEGIN  INSERT 
INTO
    vault_databases
    (ico_index,ico_name,ico_description,socket,ico,status_cd) 
VALUES
    (682,'SOE_ICO_61_271','SOE_PROD_ICO_61_BT LATAM_PROVIDER_PERU_271',16003,'61_271','A');  INSERT 
    INTO
        vault_databases
        (ico_index,ico_name,ico_description,socket,ico,status_cd) 
    VALUES
        (683,'SOE_ICO_61_272','SOE_TEST_ICO_61_BT LATAM_PROVIDER_PERU_272',17003,'61_272','A');  INSERT 
        INTO
            vault_databases
            (ico_index,ico_name,ico_description,socket,ico,status_cd) 
        VALUES
            (684,'SOE_ICO_61_273','SOE_PROD_ICO_61_BT LATAM_PROVIDER_PERU_273',16003,'61_273','A');  INSERT 
            INTO
                vault_databases
                (ico_index,ico_name,ico_description,socket,ico,status_cd) 
            VALUES
                (685,'SOE_ICO_61_274','SOE_TEST_ICO_61_BT LATAM_PROVIDER_PERU_274',17003,'61_274','A');  INSERT 
                INTO
                    vault_databases
                    (ico_index,ico_name,ico_description,socket,ico,status_cd) 
                VALUES
                    (686,'SOE_ICO_61_275','SOE_PROD_ICO_61_BT LATAM_PROVIDER_COLUMBIA_275',16003,'61_275','A');  INSERT 
                    INTO
                        vault_databases
                        (ico_index,ico_name,ico_description,socket,ico,status_cd) 
                    VALUES
                        (687,'SOE_ICO_61_276','SOE_TEST_ICO_61_BT LATAM_PROVIDER_COLUMBIA_276',17003,'61_276','A');  INSERT 
                        INTO
                            vault_databases
                            (ico_index,ico_name,ico_description,socket,ico,status_cd) 
                        VALUES
                            (688,'SOE_ICO_61_277','SOE_PROD_ICO_61_BT LATAM_PROVIDER_COLUMBIA_277',16003,'61_277','A');  INSERT 
                            INTO
                                vault_databases
                                (ico_index,ico_name,ico_description,socket,ico,status_cd) 
                            VALUES
                                (689,'SOE_ICO_61_278','SOE_TEST_ICO_61_BT LATAM_PROVIDER_COLUMBIA_278',17003,'61_278','A');      END$$  DELIMITER ;  ~  ~  ~  ~
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n                  ear ''proc_ico_150643'' at line 1

Comment: The erropr starts actually in the first line. Use backticks to escape names, not quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The error starts actually in the first line. Use backticks to escape names, not quotes.

Instead of

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS 'proc_ico_150643';
```

use

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `proc_ico_150643`;
```

You also need to correct this lines having the same issue

```
USE `doc1vault` $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_ico_150643`(
```